# Image Resizing/Scaling

Tags: python, image, scaling

trying to make a rock paper scissors and wanted to make a window, everything so far works except the size of the image, it's also not centered.

```
pygame.transform.scale = pygame.image.load('/Users/louistenant/Library/Mobile Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/Code_RPS/Rock.jpg' ),(10 , 5)

pygame.transform.scale = pygame.image.load('/Users/louistenant/Library/Mobile Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/Code_RPS/Paper.jpg' ),(10 , 5)

pygame.transform.scale = pygame.image.load('/Users/louistenant/Library/Mobile Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/Code_RPS/Scissors.jpg' ),(10 , 5)
```

I tried adding this but nothing changed(first image is code and the second one is the window.)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6N63.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtHGi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right functions, but the wrong syntax.
Instead of

```
pygame.transform.scale = pygame.image.load('/Users/louistenant/Library/Mobile Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/Code_RPS/Rock.jpg' ),(10 , 5)
```

do

```
image = pygame.image.load('/Users/louistenant/Library/Mobile Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/Code_RPS/Rock.jpg' )
image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (10 , 5))
```

As for not being centered, pygame draws from top left I believe, so you need to shift the position you specify accordingly.